# Insert into SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a simple problem. I have two tables `FROM` and `TO`. I want to copy column `Group` from `FROM` to `TO` but only the rows which match the `id_number`. It should be very simple but I am stuck.

```
insert into TO (Group)
   SELECT Group 
   FROM FROM
   WHERE FROM.id_number like TO.id_number
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO TO (Group)
   SELECT Group 
   FROM FROM
   WHERE id_number IN (SELECT id_number FROM TO)
```

This one just adds additional columns to the table, it does not update the rows as per `id_number`....

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you want to insert a whole new record? Or do you just want to update the Group field on the TO table?

Comment: tables `TO`, `FROM`, field `Group` make things a little confusing

Comment: Yeah, howabout using "Source" instead of FROM and "Target" instead of "TO". Re-using keywords in any language can be problematic

Comment: yes, I want to update only group not all records.

Comment: Recommend making up names, like Cat and Dog.  Or Person and Cthulhu.  Any nouns, really.

Comment: you are right Norla but I am using these two tables as a test before I update the real tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say "only the rows which match the id_number". That implies `update` not `insert`.

```
update [TO] set [Group] = [FROM].[Group]
from [FROM]
inner join [TO] on [FROM].id_number = [TO].id_number
```